# Indentation until new line is forced

Tags: indentation, text

I'm struggeling with a text format issue in LateX for a while now and I don't now how to solve it easily. I got a big document which is formatted like this:

Name1: blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablabla \\ (enter) 
 
Name2: blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
blablablabla \\ (enter)

etc.

This is really unreadable, and I'm looking for some kind of global setting that can transform my text (without editing the text) in this instead:

Name1: blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
                   blablablablablablablablablablabla \\ (enter) 
 
Name2: blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
                   blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
             blablablabla \\ (enter)

So what I actually like to do, is create an indent for every sentence that is too long. Is this possible to do?

Comment: if you don't have anything else than this list in your document, then you can use `\everypar` and `\hangindent`.

Comment: "without editing the text"? Does that mean zero edits to what you have shown as input?  Not even delimiting the blocks that need this special treatment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Is each of those blocks terminated by `\\ `?

Comment: @AGoldMan: Well there are some other parts that should not have the same format, thus something with \{}begin and \{}end would be preferred :)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Well, I have arround 1000 of these constructions in the document, it would be nice if I don't have to edit them all :)

Comment: @Skillmon: Yes!

Comment: You may have to do a Change ALL to convert \\ to `\par` to use `\hangindent`.  But you really should put the names in `\makebox` es.

Comment: @JohnKormylo he could redefine \\ to be `\par` if he's making an environment anyways.

Comment: your question is not very clear, Do you want to format the view in your editor, or change the typeset output, also you say in comments that the blocks end with `\\ ` but you show them as ending with `\\ (enter)`   is `\(enter)` literal text in your source file or do you mean some meta comment?

Comment: @AGoldMan - Hmm, `\def{\\}#1:{\par\hangindent=.5in \makebox[.5in][l]{#1:}}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo doesn't address the first line

Comment: It would be better to edit the source file to use standard latex syntax rather than define the incorrect syntax do do something, just edit it to be `\begin{description}\item[name 1] zzzz \item[name 2] zzzz \end{description}`

Comment: @AGoldMan - That would be handled separately at the start of the environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I totally agree, I had to make minutes for a big meeting and thought it was a good idea to do this in Latex.. Only con was that I could not write syntax that fast :p

Comment: Do you have "Names:" with different lengths? If yes, do you need to indent all text by the indentation calculated by the biggest length of "Names:"?

Comment: @ErikvanRaalte while it's not that hard to add hanging indent it would be better to edit the document, in any reasonable editor editing 2 or 2000 such blocks should be essentially the same effort.

Comment: @wipet: Good point, I would determine the indentation on the longest name in that case..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The items description look exactly as how I intended, I will find a smart way to do put this in my document! Thank you all for the suggestions!

Comment: For an easy way of taking minutes in meetings using latex see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311887/formatting-of-description-environment-with-convenience-of-easylist/311940#311940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following macros. All between `\specbegin`...`\specend` looks exactly like in your description, i.e. you need not to do any changes in your text. The indentation af all text is calculated by the longest Name.

```
\newbox\specbox
\newdimen\maxname
\def\specbegin{\begingroup
   \setbox\specbox=\vbox{}%
   \maxname=0pt
   \def\p ##1{\ifx\specend##1\specend\else \expandafter\pp\expandafter##1\fi}
   \def\pp ##1: ##2\\{%
      \setbox0=\hbox{##1: }%
      \ifdim\maxname>\wd0 \else \maxname=\wd0 \fi
      \setbox\specbox=\vbox{\hbox{##2\unskip}\nointerlineskip\box0
                            \unvbox\specbox}%
      \p 
   }
   \p
}
\def\specend{
   \loop
      \setbox\specbox=\vbox{\unvbox\specbox
         \global\setbox0=\lastbox \global\setbox1=\lastbox
      }
      \unless\ifvoid0
         \noindent \hangindent=\maxname
         \hbox to\maxname{\box0\hss}\unhbox1\endgraf
      \repeat
   \endgroup
}

\specbegin
Name1: bla bla blabla blab labla blabl abla blab labla
bla blab labl ablab labl ab lab labl abla
bla blab labl ablab labl ab lab labl abla
bla blab labl ablab labl ab lab labl abla \\
Name2: blabl abla bla bla blab labl ablab lab lablabla
bl ablab labl ablabl abl abla blabl ablab labl ablablab
bla bla bla bla \\
Long Name3: blabl abla bla bla blab labl ablab lab lablabla
bl ablab labl ablabl abl abla blabl ablab labl ablablab
bl ablab labl ablabl abl abla blabl ablab labl ablablab
bla bla bla bla \\
Name4: blabl abla bla bla blab labl ablab lab lablabla
bl ablab labl blabl ablab labl ablablab
bl ablab labl ablabl abl abla blabl ablab labl ablablab
bla bla bla bla \\
\specend
```

The macros do two iterations over text. First pass: the longest "Name" is measured and all text is stored into `\specbox`. Second pass: the text is restored from `\specbox` and used with proper `\hangindent`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{desclike}
{%
  \def\\##1{%
    \ifx##1\end%
    \else%
      \expandafter\@desclike%
    \fi##1}
  \def\@desclike##1:{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax%
    \else%
      \item[##1:]%
    \fi}%
  \begin{description}%
  \\%
}{%
  \end{description}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{desclike}
Name1: blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablabla \\ 
Name2: blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
blablablabla \\
\end{desclike}
\end{document}
```

Like this it changes the "Name1:" to boldface, but this could be changed by changing the description labels formatting.